# Stanley-Reisner ring and toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My question comes from two names.

For a finite (topological) simplicial complex $\Delta$, we have its Stanley-Reisner ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I_\Delta$. This ideal is homogeneous so we can take the $\mathrm{Proj}$ construction getting a projective variety (we assume $k$ is algebraically closed).

Because $\Delta$ is set to be finite, we have a polytope that is simplicial. Then we have a toric variety over $k$ associated to this polytope.

Do these constructions give us the same varieties? (If the answer is yes, we can know that this variety is simplicial as well.) (For this variety being simplicial, I might be wrong.)

Comment: 1. How do you produce a toric variety from your finite simplicial complex? The classical construction is from a fan, which is fairly different from a finite simplicial complex. 2. What is your definition of a simplicial variety?

Comment: @KReiser The fan is taken to be the normal fan of the polytope (see Cox, Little, Schenck, section 2.3). A toric variety is said to be simplicial if its fan is simplicial.

Comment: I think the story goes as follows: The polytope defines a toric variety + a divisor. You can scale or translate your polytope and will get the same variety, but with a different divisor. Two polytopes will define isomorphic varieties iff there is an element of $GL_n(Z)$ taking one of the to the other.

Answer (score 1):

The components of $\mathbf{P}(\Delta) = \operatorname{Proj} k[x_1,...,x_n]/I_{\Delta}$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the maximal faces of $\Delta$, so you never get a toric variety this way, except in the case of $\Delta$ being a simplex (in which case you get $\mathbf{P}(\Delta) = \mathbf{P}^n$).

Now, I'm assuming you're talking about $\Delta$ being the boundary of a simplicial polytope. In that case, there's not much of a connection between the Stanley-Reisner (projective) scheme, and the toric variety $X_P$. However, if all the facet simplices of $P$ are unimodular, i.e. of volume $1$ (or dilations of unimodular simplices), then we do in fact have that $\mathbf{P}(\Delta)$ is isomorphic to the torus-invariant anti-canonical divisor $-K_{X_P} = \sum_{F \text{ facet}} D_F \subseteq X_P$.